# Hide keyboard on scroll in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I would like to hide the keyboard on scrolling a `SingleChildScrollView` with a focused `TextFormField`.

I added a `NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>` on top of the `SingleChildScrollView`, and listen for the `ScrollStartNotification`. I then call `FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode())` to hide the keyboard.

The problem occur when the `TextFormField` is at the bottom of the screen. When i click it, it gets focus, the keyboard appears and moves the `SingleChildScrollView` up, which again fires the `ScrollStartNotification` and hides the keyboard.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The `ScrollView` widget now has a `keyboardDismissBehavior` attribute that you can use for this purpose. The attribute is inherited by `ListView`, `GridView` and `CustomScrollView`.

The attribute defaults to `ScrollViewKeyboardDismissBehavior.manual` but can be changed to `ScrollViewKeyboardDismissBehavior.onDrag`.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollView/keyboardDismissBehavior.html

**Example**

```
ListView.builder(
  keyboardDismissBehavior: ScrollViewKeyboardDismissBehavior.onDrag,
  itemCount: itemCount,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text('Item ${index + 1}'),
    );
  },
)
```

*At least at the time of this writing the attribute is not yet passed on to its parent by `CustomScrollView` in the Flutter stable branch, but a [pull request](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/66014) to add this attribute has already been merged into master on Sep 21, 2020 and will probably be available soon.*

Comment: this is correct answer!

Comment: This didn't work as well as Arsen's answer w/ GestureDetector: in the event that the list doesn't need to scroll (i.e. doesn't have enough elements) BUT the keyboard is still covering it, the keyboard won't be dismissed. This is probably only an issue when using "resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false" on the Scaffold.

Answer (score 58):

Instead of doing with NotificationListener wrap your SingleChildScrollView inside GestureDetector and dismiss the keyboard like this:

```
GestureDetector(
  behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
  onPanDown: (_) {
    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
  },
  child: SingleChildScrollView(...),
);
```

Comment: Works great with the `onPanDown` event. Will you update your answer to include this, and i will accept it. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, Just did it.

Comment: Worked to me. Thanks

Comment: Worked to me! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

We have created this simple Widget.
Wrap your scrollable view in this Widget and you're done.

```
/// A widget that listens for [ScrollNotification]s bubbling up the tree
/// and close the keyboard on user scroll.
class ScrollKeyboardCloser extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;

  ScrollKeyboardCloser({@required this.child});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
      onNotification: (scrollNotification) {
        if (scrollNotification is UserScrollNotification) {
          // close keyboard
          FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
        }
        return false;
      },
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Careful when use this one, if you have a popup in a type ahead textfield it will dismiss the popup when the textfield unfocus

Answer (score 2):

Most of the answers with GestureDetector and onPanDown are good but it wasn't enough for me. After playing with it a bit I think I found a much better solution.

```
GestureDetector(
  onVerticalDragUpdate: (details) {
    if (details.primaryDelta > 20) {
      FocusScope.of(context).detach();
    }
  },
  child: Widget(),
);
```

If you swipe up the delta is negative so this won't trigger the dismissal, same if you swipe really slowly. You can obviously adjust the delta to make it more or less responsive.
Also, `detach()` method looks a lot better that providing a new FocusScope.

Comment: This doesn't work if the child widget is a scrollview since the drag gesture doesn't bubble up to the GestureDetector.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is better to use `NotificationListener` to listen scroll rather than on just tap

```
NotificationListener(
        // ignore: missing_return
        onNotification: (notification) {
          if (notification is ScrollUpdateNotification) {
            if (notification.scrollDelta.abs() > 10 &&
                notification.dragDetails != null)
              FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
          }
        },
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: SomeChildWidget(),
        ),
      )
```

Answer (score 1):

GestureDetector will only work for "single taps", which isn't representative of all possible gestures that can be executed.
Listener listens to events that can construct gestures, such as when the pointer is pressed, moved, then released, or canceled.

```
Listener(
  onPointerDown: (_) {
    FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
    if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
      currentFocus.focusedChild.unfocus();
    }
  },
  child: MaterialApp(...),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

this is something i wrote to handle this issue. my goal was to hide keyboard when you swipe over it like you would expect on an Iphone

```html
Widget swipeOffKeyboard(BuildContext context, {Widget? child}) {
  return Listener(
    onPointerMove: (PointerMoveEvent pointer) {
      disKeyboard(pointer, context);
    },
    child: child, // your content should go here
  );
}

void disKeyboard(PointerMoveEvent pointer, BuildContext context) {
  double insets = MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom;
  double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
  double position = pointer.position.dy;
  double keyboardHeight = screenHeight - insets;
  if (position > keyboardHeight && insets > 0) FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
}
```